# Efficient shifting of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the best way for linear shifting of a vector keeping the length same and setting the empty slots to 0, something like what `valarray.shift(int n)` does.

I can think of a naive way, just wondering if there is a better one

```
int shift = 2;
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.end() - shift, v.end());
std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin() + shift, 0);

// Input: 1,2,3,4,5
// Output: 0,0,1,2,3
```

Comment: Have you tried to measure or profile (an optimized build of) the code? Is this really a bottleneck, or just a case of premature optimization? Your first concern should always be to write good, testable, readable and maintainable code. If measurements turns out to not be good enough (which often *is* good enough) then profile to find bottlenecks and optimize those, with plenty of documentation and comments (as optimizations tend to make code hard to read and maintain).

Comment: You will want to think about manually unrolling the loop, using SSE, changing the vector into a c style array or manually writing the shifting using the naive method if you want to go any faster than this.
That aside, you shouldn't really be worrying about the performance of this unless this is where your cpu spends most of its cycles on.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, yaa I am not yet at the stage of hitting any bottleneck. It's basically out of curiosity because it seems a bit strange that I need to call 2 functions to do a normal shifting, while there is a direct function for circular shifting (rotate). @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) instead, as it should probably be a little more "efficient" than `std::rotate`. Still need the `std::fill` call though.

Use it like

```
std::move(begin(v), end(v) - shift, begin(v) + shift);
std::fill(begin(v), begin(v) + shift, 0);
```

Also if the shift or size of the vector is input from outside the program, then don't forget to add some safety checks (as in [the answer by Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288501/440558)).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I myself was not so comfortable with this unnecessary circular shifting.

Answer (score 2):

I think that can limit to a call to std::copy as it follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const size_t shift {2};
    const std::vector<int> inVec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> outVec(inVec.size());
    if(inVec.size() - shift > 0)
    {
        const size_t start {inVec.size() - shift};
        std::copy(inVec.begin(), inVec.begin() + start, outVec.begin() + shift);
    }
    for(const auto& val : inVec)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(const auto& val : outVec)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's a good one, even it it doesn't do it "in place". It also needs a comment to tell readers of the code what's happening.

Comment: You're right, I miss the inplace part :) However, I think that it may dangerous to shift the vector inplace in a real case scenario. Imagine for example that an user can apply shift multiple time, on the same vector. You would probably want to keep the original data.

Comment: Thanks, Paolo for an alternative. In my current experiment though, I would prefer in-place shifting because in this case shift is not an user input.